# Closed form expressions for a sum

Tags: notation, summation-method

I was given a sum **s**, then I expressed it using sigma notation as you can see below. Now, I am supposed to find the closed form values for the said sum as shown in **eq.2**, but I am stuck at **eq.1**. I don't know how to deal with the highlighted part, am I forgetting something or did I make some mistake? Grateful for any help!

[image]

Comment: $2n$ is even, such that $\left(-1\right)^{2n}=1$.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but I had an unknown, and I didn't know how to deal with it; completely forget that I could extract the **n**, like Matt L. did in his post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(-1)^{2n}=((-1)^2)^n=1^n=1$$

Comment: I was trying to deal with negative one as if it were positive one, since the latter power to whatever is still positive one, but then remembered that the same rule doesn't apply to the former. Easy to forget the basics, thank you!